# add changes via EF to DB possible?

Tags: entity-framework

i've got a question about the tables and stored procedures which are created by aspnet_regsql.exe.
scenario:

1. new empty database: foodb
2. execute the script aspnet_regsql.exe for this Database.

now:
can i add a entity model framework for this Database, and add aditional Entities and associations to the existing Entities (e.g. ASPNET_Users) ?

best regards

Comment: are you asking if you can bring the tables, procs, etc that are created by the aspnet_regsql.exe INTO an entity framework model?

Comment: yes, and if it's possible to set a new association. e.g.: Aspnet_Users.UserId (1-m) Events.UserId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes you can bring in any database objects to an entity framework model.  I'm not sue why you would want to, because these things aren't really made to be directly accessed (there are API's to get to this data).

To your second question of adding new associations, that part I don't think you can do.  As far as memory serves, the EF designer does not allow you to just wire up non-existant association.  So you would need to actually make the associations within SQL server, and then import them into the model.

I wouldn't recommend doing this if you are still using any of the API's as it might have unintended consequences.